# Generate a keypair from a password

Tags: java, security, encryption

I would like to use asymmetric encryption based with a private key based on a password. The requirement is the security level provided must be the same of (1) using password-based symmetric encryption, (2) using asymmetric encryption in a "regular" way.

I will have to use it in Java, but the answer can be generic.

I am aware that I can generate a keypair and encrypt the privateKey with a password-based symmetric key, however, in this way I will need a server (or other storage) to store this encrypted key. I would like to avoid that. If I could generate a keypair from a password, it is not needed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't base a private key on a password. You generate a private/public key pair based on random number(s), then encrypt the private key using a symmetric encryption.

Comment: I am aware of that. That is the approach I will use if I cannot found a better solution. But for my system, I would like to avoid that since I would need a place to store the encrypted private key, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: You have not explained *why* you think you need it 'based on a password'. What difference does it make what it's based on, if anything? And why do you want to use asymmetric encryption in the first place? The common approach is exacty the other way around: generate a symmetric key and encrypt *that* with the keypair.

Answer (score 4):

If you base the private key solely on a password, it will only be as strong as the password, i.e. whoever can guess the password can get the private key.

This is comparable to generating a private/public key pair, encrypting the private key with a symmetric cipher and then publishing both together.

This of course makes the whole system weaker, since you no longer need to *have* the secret token - you only need to *know* the password.

Answer (score 3):

Every time I see this question or a variant of it asked it's usually the result of bad design decisions. Almost always, the correct answer is to generate a random RSA keypair and protect the private key using standard password-based encryption like PBKDF2 or argon2. I've only seen one use case where this made at least a little sense and that was a cryptographic token back in the day with absolutely no nonvolatile storage. You won't find it around because there's no reason to build such a token, nonvolatile storage is not exotic in 2018.

In general you can do this: java's [RSA key generation code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.html#initialize-int-java.security.SecureRandom-) accepts an instance of [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) which the Oracle providers use to generate the candidate primes for RSA. You can subclass SecureRandom (I think) to provide a class that uses the password to seed a deterministic, repeatable sequence of random numbers such that every time you call [`KeyPairGenerator. generateKeyPair()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.html#generateKeyPair--) the same keypair (including the private key) is generated. The bouncycastle library includes an example, [`FixedSecureRandom`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/prng/FixedSecureRandom.html), that can be used as a model. Note that the deterministic RNG still has to be cryptographically secure, apart from the fact that it will not have enough entropy. `FixedSecureRandom` is not secure, it simply returns the pre-supplied bytes directly as output. Perhaps you can merge `FixedSecureRandom` with one of the other CSPRNGs in the [`org.bouncycastle.crypto.prng`](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/prng/package-frame.html) package.